# Getting title of UIButton in event handler

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, uibutton

I create a button and set title as "Click here". When I press that button I want to get that button title and log it. Here's my code, where am I going wrong?

```
-(void)clicketbutton {
    UIButton *mybutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [mybutton setTitle:@"Click here"  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [mybutton addTarget:self  
       action:@selector(displayvalue:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
}

-(void)displayvalue:(id)sender {       
    UIButton *resultebutton= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    resultebutton=sender;// pls clear here.. my question here , it it possible or not. if possible how ?
    NSLog(@" The buttontitile is %@ ", [resultebutton.Title] // here also.
}
```

Answer (score 72):

Your displayvalue: method should look something like this:

```
-(void)displayvalue:(id)sender {       
    UIButton *resultButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@" The button's title is %@.",  resultButton.currentTitle);
}
```

(Please check out the documentation in XCode, it would have given you the right answer.)

Answer (score 13):

```
-(void)displayvalue:(id)sender 
{
    UIButton *resultebutton= (UIButton*)sender;
    NSLog(@"The button title is %@ ", resultebutton.titleLabel.text);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a bit of an old question, but this is probably the neatest way to resolve this one.

```
NSLog(@"The button title is: %@", [sender currentTitle]);
```

**Edit**
I've just realised that this is depending on the fact that you have set the receiving parameter to `UIButton*`. Rather than using the default `id`, creating a `UIButton` object and casting `(id)sender` to that button. Cut out the middle man and just set the function signature to

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender{
  NSLog(@"Button title: %@",sender.currentTitle);
}
```

This is effectively casting the function parameter

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)clicketbutton {
    UIButton *mybutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [mybutton setTitle:@"Click here"  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [mybutton addTarget:self  
       action:@selector(displayvalue:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
}
-(void)displayvalue:(id)sender {       

     NSLog(@"The title is %@ ", [mybutton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]);

}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work at all. For it to work `mybutton` needs to be an instance variable, but then you also need to assign the button to the instance variable in `-clicketbutton` - currently that method is using a local variable. In other words, `mybutton` represents different things in your two methods.

Comment: @ThomasMüller correct. The `myButton` variable is out of scope of the displayValue: function. This would work, however, if they used `sender` as the receiver rather than `myButton`