# Swift: How can I declare a statement based off the title of a button?

Tags: string, text, swift, uibutton, hiddenfield

I have a button that's title is set to "calculator" When this button in my view controller is tapped, it hides and shows a bunch of objects and it changes to the title of the button to "back":

```
@IBAction func calculatorButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    calculatorContainer.hidden = false
    inspirationLabel.hidden = true
    beginningLabel.hidden = true
    menuExampleButton.hidden = true
    aboutButton.hidden = true
    calculatorButton.setTitle("Back", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

When the title is set to "back", and when that button is clicked, I want everything that was hidden to be shown and everything that was shown to be hidden. When the title is set to "calculator", I want everything from the above code to occur. How can I do this?

Comment: You could have an `if` statement in there that looks at the currently set title?

Comment: Ok @Thilo . I am new to swift, so could you do me a huge favor and just write out the if statement for me? I have an idea of what it is, I'm just not 100%.

Comment: How about you try that idea, and if it does not work, come back for help? Do you know how to get at the current title?

Comment: No, that's the problem @Thilo

Comment: Btw, instead of using the button title to control this (probably causes problem when you change to another language), you could also use one of those `hidden` flags. Or make an entirely new property.

Comment: People trying to do the same thing in ObjectiveC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900867/getting-title-of-uibutton-in-event-handler

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
@IBAction func calculatorButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    calculatorContainer.hidden = !calculatorContainer.hidden
    inspirationLabel.hidden = !inspirationLabel.hidden
    beginningLabel.hidden = !beginningLabel.hidden
    menuExampleButton.hidden = !menuExampleButton.hidden
    aboutButton.hidden = !aboutButton.hidden
    calculatorButton.setTitle("Back", forState: UIControlState.Normal)


    if !calculatorContainer.hidden{

            inspirationLabel.hidden = true
            beginningLabel.hidden = true
            menuExampleButton.hidden = true
            aboutButton.hidden = true

    } 
}
```

This will switch back and forth between hidden and not hiding your image.